# Ruby Type Error: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested, typeerror

```
rideshare_data = {
  DR0001: [
    {
      DATE: "02_03_2016",
      COST: 10,
      RIDER_ID: "RD0003",
      RATING: 3
    },
    {
      DATE: "02_03_2016",
      COST: 30,
      RIDER_ID: "RD0015",
      RATING: 4
    },
    {
      DATE: "02_05_2016",
      COST: 45,
      RIDER_ID: "RD0003",
      RATING: 2
    }
  ],
  DR0002: [
    {
      DATE: "02_03_2016",
      COST: 25,
      RIDER_ID: "RD0073",
      RATING: 5
    },
    {
      DATE: "02_04_2016",
      COST: 15,
      RIDER_ID: "RD0013",
      RATING: 1
    },
    {
      DATE: "02_5_2016",
      COST: 35,
      RIDER_ID: "RD0066",
      RATING: 3
    }
  ]
}

rideshare_data.each do |driver_id, driver_data|
  money_earned = 0
  driver_data.each do |rides|
    rides.each do |ride, ride_data|
      money_earned = [ride_data][:COST].reduce(:+)
      puts "#{driver_id} earned #{money_earned} total"
    end
  end
end
```

So I have a dataset of arrays and hashes, and I am trying to find the total money earned for each driver by summing the :COST keys. No matter what I try in the last block, I get the error no implicit conversion of Symbol/Hash/String into Integer. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `[]` on an array, Ruby expects you to pass an integer, as arrays can only be accessed by their index, and that's why it returns such error.

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

The result of `[ride_data]`, gives you a string within an array, so, you don't have the ability to pass a symbol, accessing a key as if it'd be a Hash object.

As your `rideshare_data` is a hash, containing different values for each key (driver id), you can just iterate over each key values and get the value of each COST key, and do the operation you need:

```
rideshare_data.each_with_object([]) do |(key, value), array|
  array << "#{key} earned #{value.sum { |ride| ride[:COST] }} total"
end.each { |total| puts total } 

# DR0001 earned 85 total
# DR0002 earned 75 total
```

There you iterate over each value in `rideshare_data`, using an initial empty array as a memo where to store your data, with sum, you collect each value for COST keys and sum them. The `each` on the final is just to show each value within the resulting array.

Depending on your Ruby version, you might need map and sum instead just sum (`value.map { |ride| ride[:COST] }.sum`).

Comment: Maybe just a `map` rather than `each_with_object([])` here? :)

Comment: Yes, that's right, something like `rideshare_data.map {  |key, values| [key, values.sum { |value| value[:COST] }] }` would also work.